# Data from Two tables duplicating on join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook, laravel

I have got two tables , I would use facebook POST as an example.

Post Table

Comment Table

My query

```
   $result = DB::table('posts')
            ->join('comments', 'posts.post_ID', '=', 'comments.post_ID')
            ->get();
```

I will receive an array of posts and comments merge. For each comments that exist , they will have the posts data.

What i want is to be able to do something like

```
foreach($posts as $post){
     foreach($post['comment']{

     }
}
```

Any idea how i can do that?

Comment: can you explain more of what you want to achieve? `For each comments that exist , they will have the posts data.` specially this part.

Comment: That's normal behaviour for SQL.  Just ignore the port portion of the data when looping.  Or if you don't need the post part, just do `select comments.*`

Comment: So what is the problem, joining looks fine. What are fields in both tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$result = DB::table('posts')
        ->join('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id')
        ->get();
```

In the view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

    {{ $post->post_title }}
    {{ $post->message }}

@endforeach
```

Make sure that, field names in `->join('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id')` are right or change accordingly. `post_title/comment_text` is used to demonstrate the example, change to it's original table's field name and `{{  }}` is used in the example to echo the data, if you are not using `Blade` then use `echo $post->post_title` instead.

### Update::

If you use `Eloquent` then use:

```
// Assumed you have defined comments as relationship method
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get(); // it's faster and called eager loading
```

Then in the view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

    {{ $post->post_title }}

    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)

        {{ $comment->message }}

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: I"m trying it out, when i do this , i get lots of duplicate of post.

Comment: Sorry! didn't understand what duplicates, you are queying for all and if there are duplicates then maybe you saved duplicates in your database.posts.

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/jk4JK , I get this when i dump. Don't seem have array in array. Thanks for helping out :D

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't get a nested array back from that kind of operation, unless Laravel does some kind of magic when processing joined results

Comment: @GordanM Seems like eloquent Eager Load is the way to go?

Comment: @FlyingAtom, Using `$posts = Post::with('comments')->get()` you'll get a collection of all `Post` model so use a loop like I did in my updated answer or to access the first `Post` you may try `$post->first()->comments` where `comments` is also a collection.

Comment: Trying to grab comments , something seem to be wrong with my models, wont grab the comments hmm

Comment: If you even try my first (updated in the view) code example then it'll work because you were able to fetch posts and comments as seen [here](http://laravel.io/bin/jk4JK).

Comment: First will have issue between both table has got the column comment plus it has multiple comment. I'm trying Eloquent out http://laravel.io/bin/1Wd2x

Comment: So, what's wrong with `Eloquent`, relation looks fine and should work.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha return $this->hasMany('Comment','post_ID','post_ID'); Had to specify those 2

Comment: What fields do you have in your tables, `primary key` and `Foreign key` for relationship ?

Comment: Looks you have custom `primary key/foreign key` and you made it, Oh! Really glad to see it :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I will receive an array of posts and comments merge. For each comments that exist , they will have the posts data.

This is correct SQL behavoir when using a join. You will get the contents of both the rows inside the `posts` and `comments` rows on your `JOIN`.

According to [Laravel 4.2's documentation on the `join` method](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_join), the parameters of the join function are:

```
join($table, $one, $operator = null, $two = null, $type = 'inner', $where = false)
```

Using an `INNER JOIN`, you are only going to get rows returned to you with your query (using an inner join) if you have a comment for all of the posts that you want data from. Additionally, with your `INNER JOIN`, if there is no comment on your post, you will not get any posts returned to you.

Also, you are not going to be able to separate all of your comments from your posts, which may mean that you are getting results returned for posts that you

The simple way to solve this for you would be to make two eloquent models:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function getComments() {
        return $this->hasMany('Comments', 'post_id');
    }
}

class Comments extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'comments';
}
```

From that you can query for all of the posts with [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading):

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
```

and inside your view, you go:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    // echo the $post? (title, author etc)
    foreach($post->comments() as $comment) {
       // echo the $comment? (author, content etc)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not eager loading, eager loading would be `$posts = Post::with('comments')->get()`. In your example `$posts = Post::get()` still the comments model will be loaded dynamically on call which is bad (n+1 problem).

Comment: Look for this `Thankfully, we can use eager loading to drastically reduce the number of queries. The relationships that should be eager loaded may be specified via the with method` to find out what eager loading is on [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading).

Comment: There is some additional misinformation here.  Laravel actually defaults to inner joins.  Additionally, an inner join would only return posts which have comments and those comments.  A left join would return all posts and comments for those posts.  Posts that don't have comments would have their comment columns null.

Comment: You are both correct. Thanks guys. I have edited my answer to fix my grammar and eager loading mistakes.